# Weather "events" grouped based on time differences in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of surface weather observations (fzraHrObs) organized by a station identifier code ('usaf') and date. fzraHrObs has several columns of weather data. The station code and date (datetime objects) look like:

```
usaf      dat
716270    2014-11-23 12:00:00
          2015-12-20 08:00:00
          2015-12-20 12:00:00
716280    2015-12-19 08:00:00
          2015-12-19 09:00:00
```

I want to group these observations into 'events' by station, in which an observation occurring <6 hours after the previous observation counts in the same event. I then want to output the event start time, end time, and number of obs in the event to a dataframe. Given the example data above, I'd like the output to look something like this:

```
usaf      eventNum   start                end                     count
716270    1          2014-11-23 12:00:00  2014-11-23 12:00:00     1   
          2          2015-12-20 09:00:00  2015-12-20 12:00:00     2     
716280    1          2015-12-19 08:00:00  2015-12-19 09:00:00     2
```

I'm currently doing this with for/if loops and dicts but am working on switching things over to pandas since it's been much more efficient.

My initial thought was to do a diff of dat on each row grouped by station and get that in hours, so I do have a column 'diff' which shows this. I'm having trouble figuring out how to get event starts/ends/durations without reverting to ugly for and if loops however. I'm guessing something involving fzraHrObs[fzraHrObs['diff']>=6] will be involved as well?

Comment: If you have three observations at 5-hour intervals, does the third one still count as the same event (as it occurred less than 6 hours after the previous one), or is it a new event (as it occurred more than 6 hours after the initial event)?

Comment: Good question. Yes - the third one would count as the same event. Each observation within the event is allowed to be separated by 5 or fewer hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer in your comment means it is easy to avoid a loop, as you only need to look back to the previous event.

```
df['new_event'] = df.groupby('usaf')['dat'].apply(lambda s: s.diff().dt.seconds > 6*3600)
```

Output:

```
     usaf                 dat new_event
0  716270 2014-11-23 12:00:00     False
1  716270 2015-12-20 08:00:00      True
2  716270 2015-12-20 12:00:00     False
3  716280 2015-12-19 08:00:00     False
4  716280 2015-12-19 09:00:00     False
```

Increase the event count at `True` values:

```
df['event'] = df.groupby('usaf')['new_event'].cumsum().astype('int')
```

Output:

```
     usaf                 dat new_event  event
0  716270 2014-11-23 12:00:00     False      0
1  716270 2015-12-20 08:00:00      True      1
2  716270 2015-12-20 12:00:00     False      1
3  716280 2015-12-19 08:00:00     False      0
4  716280 2015-12-19 09:00:00     False      0
```

Now group by event, and use `agg` to apply multiple functions, including `first` and `last` to get the start and end date:

```
df.groupby(['usaf', 'event'])['dat'].agg(['first', 'last', 'count'])
```

Output:

```
                           first                last  count
usaf   event                                               
716270 0     2014-11-23 12:00:00 2014-11-23 12:00:00      1
       1     2015-12-20 08:00:00 2015-12-20 12:00:00      2
716280 0     2015-12-19 08:00:00 2015-12-19 09:00:00      2
```

All that is left to do is clean up the indices!

Comment: This is excellent - thanks so much! Just started using pandas a few days ago and your examples are very helpful. The agg function is really convenient for what I'm working on.

Comment: One more question that you may also be able to provide insight on:

I also want to separately combine events that are separated by <24 h - i.e. where the a new event starts <24 hours after the previous event ended. In this case I would need to look at something like (start[idx]  - end[idx-1]). I suspect the best way to do this would be by using the original fzraHrObs df with the event #/ new_event columns?

Comment: Actually just figured this out. I created a column with the difference between the current and previous row's time:
fzraHrObs['prev_dat'] = fzraHrObs['dat'].groupby([fzraHrObs['usaf']]).shift(1)
and then calculated the difference between them. After this I checked if that difference was <24 h and if not, set new_event to false fzraHrObs.ix[fzraHrObs.timedif < 24, 'new_event'] = False 

This block of code is before the cumsum and agg lines above.

Comment: Glad you figured it out :)